# Python module object has no attribute struct_time with homebrew on OSX Sierra but not debian

Tags: python, macos

I have the strangest problem. This Python code works on a Raspberry Pi running stock Debian:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
now = datetime.now()
print( now )
print( now.strftime( "%d/%m/%y %H:%M" ) )
```

And gives the expected:

```
2017-07-17 08:17:17.567342
17/07/17 08:17
```

On OSX Sierra with Python installed via Homebrew it gives:

```
2017-07-17 08:10:21.196849
2017-07-17 08:10:21.197579
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 6, in <module>
    print( now.strftime( "%d/%m/%y %H:%M" ) )
  File "/Users/craign/Desktop/time.py", line 6, in <module>
    print( now.strftime( "%d/%m/%y %H:%M" ) )
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'struct_time'
```

I have:

```
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.2.4
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Anybody have any ideas? I've scoured the interwebs, StackOverflow, etc. for a crazy amount of time on this and feel like a total idiot.

Comment: And what version of python do you have on Debian (raspberry pi)?

Comment: I think there is a problem with name conflicts during importing. Actually you import [datetime.time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time). However `struct_time` is member of [time]
 module(https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time). Somehow during imports one name is shadowed by another. What I would suggest is to use **as** for all datetime imports i.e. `from datetime import time as datetimetime`, and check if this solves the issue

Comment: I believe running.t is correct. OP's module is named time.py which probably shadows python's time builtin.

Comment: Python 2.7.9 on Debian. BobDarph that was exactly right. I just renamed my code to "timetest.py" and it works. I am indeed an idiot. I learned about importing "as" here as well, so thanks to running.t!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your script's name `time.py` by `my_time.py` or whatever pops in your mind and remove the file `time.pyc` that the compilation has created and it should work as expected. Nothing wrong with your setup, this is the expected behaviour and it can be easily reproduce.

**Why?**: The module `time` already exists in python and you overrode it by mistake.