# python not able to print datetime info

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to write a simple python file that outputs datetime info to the terminal. Originally I saved my file as `time.py` which I realized later was a bad idea. I re-saved my file as `blah.py`. Now, whenever I run my program I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'struct_time'

I've seen several other posts that say I need to delete the `time.pyc` file that was created and that should fix my problem but it doesn't fix it, I still get the error.

Here's my code:

```
import datetime

currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()

print (currentDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

This is my first python program so I'm probably missing something really basic. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: is it python2 or python3?

Comment: @Devsh Kumar Singh sorry, it's 2.7.10

Comment: Try deleting the whole folder where the file was created, or if this file was part of a python module, uninstall and reinstall it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python module object has no attribute struct\_time with homebrew on OSX Sierra but not debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145575/python-module-object-has-no-attribute-struct-time-with-homebrew-on-osx-sierra-bu)

Comment: I created the file in my root (~) so I can't delete that folder. @DeveshKumarSingh can you point out what files/folders i should delete in my root specifically?

Comment: The OP has mentioned that this solution didn't work for him @MedAli, so it's not a duplicate I think

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145575/python-module-object-has-no-attribute-struct-time-with-homebrew-on-osx-sierra-bu), where a very similar issue was encountered.

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak as a quick test, I suggest that you create a folder /tmp/tmp_time_test and create your code inside that folder.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it's a duplicate, the OP just needed sometime to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DeveshKumarSingh for the advice that resulted in my answer. I looked and there was a `time.py` and `time.pyc` that was created in my root folder. I deleted these files and now my program runs just fine.